# How to access PC via Remote Desktop Connection and access SMB folder

Tags: networking, router, remote-desktop, samba

[image: Home Topology]

My home topology is like in the image shown.
My ISP (My Republic) gives me public IP, but I don't want to use their router (Fiberhome HG6243C) because my Asus router has more features and overall better.
My Republic and their wisdom uses TR069_Internet so, I can't easily changes it to bridge and their customer service is not helping at all.

I know I am behind double NAT

My Goal: Can use Remote Desktop Connection to my PC (10.0.0.2) and access Samba Folder (from PC) from Internet (outside home network).

I am using Windows 11 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, why not clean up your network and get rid of the Double NAT by turning of NAT on the RT-AX56U and adding a route on your ISP router for 10.0.0.x to to 192.168.1.2?   You can further refine this by setting 192.168.1.2 as a DMZ on 192.168.1.1 which will forward all incoming traffic to your 152.x.x.x address to your ASUS router.

Even if all you do is set up port forwarding or a DMZ on your ISP router to your ASUS router, you can run a VPN server on it (I don't know if you can do this with the default firmware - if not, you can do it with DD-WRT) - and then connect to your home network via VPN.    At that point it becomes easy to RDP to your PC and to access your SAMBA fileshare across the VPN.

Comment: Well... I'll try this first before I try to nuke everything and make 192.168.1.1 as main router, connect to 192.168.1.2 (Asus router) via LAN port (instead of WAN) and let 192.168.1.2 as DHCP server.

I just wonder if it is possible? Making the 2nd router act as DHCP server